# Problem with dependent types function in Idris

Tags: idris

I have just started reading a book "Type-driven development" and tried my simple example with dependent types. It should return a string for negative numbers and Integer for the positive ones.
I started with 2 holes:

```
StringOrInt : Bool -> Type
StringOrInt b =
  case b of
    True => Integer
    False => String

getStringOrInt : (x : Integer) -> StringOrInt (x > 0)
getStringOrInt x =
  case x > 0 of
    True => ?x
    False => ?s
```

If I take a look at holes definition it looks very complicated and not helpful at all:

```
x : case with block in Prelude.Interfaces.Prelude.Interfaces.Integer implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Ord, method > (ifThenElse (intToBool (prim__eqBigInt x 0))
                (Delay EQ)
                (Delay (ifThenElse (intToBool (prim__sltBigInt x
                                                               0))
                                   (Delay LT)
                                   (Delay GT))))
    x
    0 of
      True => Integer
      False => String
```

So how to write this function?

Comment: my first guess is that by moving from explicit `True` and `False` (as in the book) to `x > 0`, you've made the problem much harder. Why? You'll see in ch 8 where Brady introduces theorem proving and mentions that comparisons like `=`, `<` etc. don't provide enough information in the type to guarantee the behaviour I was used to assuming. For example, there's nothing to say `x > y` doesn't always return `False` for all `x`, `y`. If you're just starting out, prepare to have your mind blown

Comment: though as a relative newbie, I may be massively overcomplicating it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me wait till the Chapter 8 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with` rather than `case` to leverage dependent pattern matching and have the type checker substitute the appropriate Boolean for `x > 0` in the result type for each alternative:

```
StringOrInt : Bool -> Type
StringOrInt True  = Integer
StringOrInt False = String

getStringOrInt : (x : Integer) -> StringOrInt (x > 0)
getStringOrInt x with (x > 0)
  getStringOrInt x | True  = x
  getStringOrInt x | False = "<= 0"
```